# React Native Error Cannot find module 'metro-config/src/defaults/blacklist'

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, metro-bundler

I'm currently working on a project in React Native, yesterday it was working perfectly with no errors, and now all of a sudden I'm getting this error.

```
error Cannot find module 'metro-config/src/defaults/blacklist'
Require stack:
- /Users/sri/Downloads/cc_x/reactnativelcsapp/VitalitiApp/metro.config.js
```

I've tried soo many solutions, removing the node modules and installing it back, updating the modules, looking to change the backlist. I've checked my files and I can't find the blacklist file but I'm trying to fix it but honestly have no idea how to fix it. I was wondering if anyone would know what to do.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

the blacklist file seems to be renamed as exclusionList

```
const blacklist = require('metro-config/src/defaults/exclusionList');
```

use this line instead in metro.config.js

Comment: More information can be found here.

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/3295

Answer (score 4):

In newer versions of `metro-config` the function is now called `exclusionList`. So change the `blacklist` reference with `exclusionList` in `metro-config.js` file which is located in the project root directory.

```
const exclusionList = require('metro-config/src/defaults/exclusionList');
```

If still issue persists, then add `metro-config` as a dev dependency:

```
npm install -D metro-config
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same Issue as others. Changing it to

`const exclusionList = require('metro-config/src/defaults/exclusionList');`

Fixed my issue.

I had to create `metro.config.js` and insert the following code since I was using AWS Amplify:

```
const blacklist = require('metro-config/src/defaults/exclusionList');

module.exports = {
    resolver: {
        blacklistRE: blacklist([/amplify\/#current-cloud-backend\/.*/]),
    },
    transformer: {
        getTransformOptions: async () => ({
            transform: {
                experimentalImportSupport: false,
                inlineRequires: false,
            },
        }),
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error in *myapp/node_modules/expo-yarn-workspaces/index.js*
From my require stack so I opened this file and found `const blacklist = require('metro-config/src/defaults/blacklist');` into my app node modules.

So I changed it to

```
const blacklist = require('metro-config/src/defaults/exclusionList');
```

which fixed my problem